# How to detect ads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a browser extension that will detect advertisements. I don't want an AdBlock, I just wish to detect how many ads are encountered. I don't know where to begin searching for ads in the HTML, though. Any help for a good first start?

Comment: Ads don't follow any web specification or standard. There are thousands of slight differences in their actual implementations. This is a very broad topic which you'll need to investigate yourself. For example by inspecting the source code of AdBlock or uBlock, and the most common detection lists such as EasyList.

Comment: **Just out of curiosity**, if you'll decide on what you'll use, I'd be really grateful if you would leave a comment under my answer. (maybe a GitHub/GitLab/Bitbucket repo, or something) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

Most adblockers catch the ads **via some form of a regex match**.

I would recommend you to start with the [**adblockpluscore**](https://github.com/adblockplus/adblockpluscore) repository, since it's open source and you can quickly run through the source code.

Start with the [**test**](https://github.com/adblockplus/adblockpluscore/tree/master/test) directory, particularly peeking into the [**patterns.ini**](https://github.com/adblockplus/adblockpluscore/blob/master/test/data/patterns.ini) file and see the common patterns, when determining different sources of ads.

Search for these sections in **patterns.ini**:

- **General tracking systems**
- **Third-party tracking domain**

---

You can expect, that **your initial solutions won't be too effective**, since ads come in different forms of data, but **you'll find common patterns between many of them**.